# Error while inflating class in window manager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-activity

Code

```
public class FloatingWindow extends Service{
WindowManager wm;
LinearLayout ll;
LayoutInflater li;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    View myview;
    li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            500, 1000, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
    myview = li.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_window, null); // your layout here
    wm.addView(myview, params);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/allusers"
    android:layout_below="@id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <ImageButton
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingVertical="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Online"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:id="@+id/online"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>





    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/message_list"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/allusers"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/add_image"
        android:id="@+id/add_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <View

        android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/add_image"
        android:id="@+id/midleft"
        android:layout_width="0.5px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <EditText
        android:paddingVertical="5dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:hint="Write a message..."
        android:id="@+id/input_message"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/add_image"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_message" />

    <View
        android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send_message"
        android:id="@+id/midright"
        android:layout_width="0.5px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/send_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/send_message"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Send" />

    <View
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottomline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5px"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Im getting this exception whenever i try to bring up the floating window... im also new to window manager so not sure on whats causing the problem... one thing i learned is the xml file cant have an appbar... but mine doesn't have but still showing an error... can someone help me out please......

Comment: if you look at the error it's not the problem with your windows manager but the service you are trying to run. In the very first line it is written that unable to create service :). First make sure your service is being created successfully then move ahead.

Comment: If i try to inflate another activity which also doesn't contain an appbar it works fine @Umair so the problem isnt with creating it

Comment: what android you test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys the problem was here

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

I literally had to 'comment' every line to see where the problem was because there was no problem anywhere else

I set the height to 50dp and now works fine